# Java - Regex to have value validated

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to generalise Regex-java like if I give value and pattern than the method should return true or false `if the given value matches the given pattern - TRUE else FALSE`.

following is the method I tried with simple Alphanumeric

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {
    public static boolean isValidInput(String value, String pattern) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        Pattern walletInputPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher walletMatcher = walletInputPattern.matcher(value);
        if (walletMatcher.matches()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        String inputValue = "45645";
        if (isValidInput(inputValue, pattern)) {
            System.out.println("Alphanumeric");
        } else {
            System.out.println("OOPS");
        }
    }
}
```

but I gave wrong input and still it prints the TRUE..

what is the mistake I do here....??..

thanks for your inputs and spending your valuable time :)

Comment: so u want only numbers to be true?

Comment: 45645 is alphanumeric and matches the pattern

Comment: Do you mean the regex should require *both* alpha and numeric chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the right result because `45645` is indeed an alphanumeric value.

If you want to make sure the value is a combination of numbers and letters then you need a different expression:

```
String pattern = "^(?!^[0-9]+$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
```

- `(?!^[0-9]+$)`: This makes sure the string isn't just a combination of digits.
- `(?!^[a-zA-Z]+$)`: This makes sure the string isn't just a combination of letters.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`: This matches a combination of letters and digits.

Comment: this still accepts the string only if I don't give the numbers Ex: sniffer than it prints Alphanumeric

Comment: thanks for the answer, it should accept only Alphanumeric if the value contains only string than it should return false and vice versa

Answer (score 3):

I believe this `lookahead-based` regex should work for you:

```
String pattern = "^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
```

This ensures that:

1. There is at least one alphabetic character in the input
2. There is at least one digit in the input
3. The input is comprised of ONLY alphanumerics